# How do I use display method and call constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, instance

I'm required to use a variable for x and y. I must set up a method to get x, y. I must use a method to set x and y. I must use a display method to display the points of x and y. Then use a constructor that accepts user input and sets them to x and y. Finally create a main class that creates 2 instances of x and y. I think my problem is occurring my display method. My program compiles/builds with no errors; however nothing displays or prompts user for input.  Do I possibly need to call my constructor in the first class before trying to call the first class in the main method?

First File:

```
public class Point2D extends JFrame
{
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   private String x;
   private String y;


   public String getX()
   {
       return x;

   }
   public String getY()
   {
       return y;

   }

   public void setValue(String whatIsX, String whatIsY)
   {
      x = whatIsX;
      y = whatIsY;

   }

   public void display()
   {
      System.out.println(x);
      System.out.println(y);
   }

   public void Point2D()
   {
      System.out.println("Please enter value for X >>");
      input.nextLine();
      x = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Please enter value for Y >>");
      input.nextLine();
      y = input.nextLine();
   }

}
```

2nd File:

```
public class MainPoint2D 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Point2D a = new Point2D();
       Point2D b = new Point2D();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you never call `display` method, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `void` from your "constructor":

```
 public Point2D()
 {
  System.out.println("Please enter value for X >>");
  input.nextLine();
  x = input.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Please enter value for Y >>");
  input.nextLine();
  y = input.nextLine();
 }
```

Constructors don't have return types, and the compiler is treating this as a class method.

Also, don't forget to call any methods you want to execute after you create your object:

```
   Point2D a = new Point2D();
   Point2D b = new Point2D();
   a.display();
   b.display();
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **void** in the **public void Point2D()**

Answer (score 1):

`public void Point2D()` defines a method named "Point2D" with a `void` return type, not a constructor. Constructors don't have any return type, not even `void`. Change that to `public Point2D()`.

Currently, your `main` method is calling the default `Point2D` constructor, which is not defined, so the compiler provides an empty one for you.

Answer (score 0):

I thik you want to change this

```
public void Point2D()
   {
      System.out.println("Please enter value for X >>");
      input.nextLine();
      x = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Please enter value for Y >>");
      input.nextLine();
      y = input.nextLine();
   }
```

to this

```
public Point2D()
   {
      System.out.println("Please enter value for X >>");
      input.nextLine();
      x = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Please enter value for Y >>");
      input.nextLine();
      y = input.nextLine();
   }
```